# How to remove outliers from distance matrix or Hierarchical clustering in R?

Tags: r

I have some questions

First, I don't know how to find and remove outliers in distance matrix or symmetry matrix.

Second, also I used Hierarachical clustering with Average linkage.

My data is `engmale161` (already made symmetry matrix with DTW )

```
engmale161 <- na.omit(engmale161)
engmale161 <- scale(engmale161)
d <- dist(engmale161, method = "euclidean")
hc1_engmale161 <- hclust(d, method="average")
```

and I find optimize index 4 with silhouette, wss & gap.

```
>sub_grp <- cutree(hc1_engmale161,h=60, k = 4)
>table(sub_grp)
>table(sub_grp)
sub_grp  
  1   2   3   4
 741  16   7   1 
> subset(sub_grp,sub_grp==4)
4165634865 
         4 


>fviz_cluster(list(data = engmale161, cluster = sub_grp), geom = "point")
```

[image]

So, I think the right upper point(4165634865) is outlier and it has only one point.
How to delete the outlier in H-C algorithm.

Comment: Hey, maybe you can elaborate more? We do the clustering to see how similar are our samples to one another. So you should do the clustering first, remove points which you think are outliers and redo the clustering. Why do you prefer to remove the outlier at the start?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't remove it from the data before you construct the distance matrix? Doesn't 4165634865 identify it for you? If not try `which(subgrp==4)`, since the group values are listed in the order of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

just some ideas.
in a nutshell,

- don't do "na.omit" on engmale161.  find the outlier(s) using
- quantiles and box-and-whiskers put outliers to NA in the dist matrix
- proceed with your processing

long version:

- "dist" behaves nicely with NAs (from the R documentation, "Missing
  values are allowed, and are excluded from all computations involving
  the rows within which they occur. Further, when Inf values are
  involved, all pairs of values are excluded when their contribution to
  the distance gave NaN or NA)"
- to find an outlier I would use concepts from exploratory statistics.
  use "quantile" with default probs and na.rm = true (because your dist
  matrix still contains NAs) --> you'll get values for the quartiles
  (dataset split in 4: 0-25%, 25-50%m and so on). 25-75 is the "box".
  To find the "whiskers" is a debated topic. the standard approach is
  to find the InterQuartileRange (IQR), which is third-first quartile,
  then first quartile - 1.5*IQR is the "lower" whiskers, and third
  quartile + 1.5*IQR is the "upper" whisker. Any value outside the
  whiskers is to be considered an outlier. Mark them as NA, and proceed.

Best of luck, and my compliments for being someone who actually looks at the data!